# Setting Up a NAS with 4 hard drives that are treated as 4 physical not arrayed drives

Tags: networking, router, raid, nas

Problem:  Nas with 4 drive bays.  I have 3 - 4tb RED WD NASware 3.04 drives.  I don't want to run a raid system.  I want to setup each drive as a single physical drive and a drive letter assigned to each (so lets say T, U, and V). 
Purpose of NAS I have is that I am saving my entire movie collection on it so no need to get up and look for it in my collection or depend on DVD or Bluray player.)

This setup will allow for me to watch movies on any desktop or laptop and when in the right room, watch the movie on 50 inch plus 1080p Samsung HDTV.  All is done via wires, no wireless involved.
In terms of drive letters it might look like this in Explorer (before the Red and after the red it will just read red for WD or Hitachi)
T:  Mediasrv1 (1 hitachi)
U:  Mediasrv2 (1 hitachi not connected to first)
v:  Mediasrv3 (wd 4tb)

Curious side note:  1 of the 3 drives has the typical full label filled from top to bottom.  2 that arrived together apparently using new label where the center of the letter is blank.  I have confirmed firmware and mdl are the same on all three.

The WD and 2 Hitachi had been setup as raid 0 strip (x1).  The X1 was added by the NAS.  I had no issues using these drives as three distinct drives.  The old label version went fine in installing and transferring files to.  The second I changed a setting that showed the drive only using about 3400GB to 3725GB and that is when issues started.

Steps taken include:
* hard reset (if pushing in pin with system off for 30 seconds is correct)
* delete all raid 0 arrays for the WD/Hit and any of the Red drives
* Use their software called Dashboard which runs on my desktop
* Tried fixes via the Web Gui access by ip address.  
* Gave the computer a name:  mediasrv (but it doesn't show that way in the router list of connected devices)
* Issues with the window services on the NAS
* Tried matching the 2 drives with shorter labels into system to ensure no conflict.
* Hard Reset (supposedly hold a pin hole down for 30 seconds)
* Setting up with no drives, then 1 drive, then 2 drives
* All previous setups/drives removed from NAS software and system
* No matter what I do, router doesn't see NAS Name of mediasrv
* Windows Explorer even refuses to map a special folder on each of the three drives, name is Test X where x is 1,2,3 and no number is used twice.

My Equipment Stats:
Desktop PC 
*Intel 6700K
*EVGA 1070ti FTW 2
*Asus Z-170 Deluxe, 16gb (2x8) Corsair DDR 4 2600mhz, 2 Network Connections
*3 Optical Drives (personal preference)
*Corsair 1000 Watt PSU
*Windows 7 Pro 64bit SP1 as of 10/31/19
*Of course mouse, keyboard, monitor, speakers
*Sound Blaster X-fi Fatality class sound
*Storage via 1 Samsung 850 2.5" 500GB as OS drive, 2 WD 4tb Black Cavs (AHCI no raid - controller is even disabled in bios)
Side note:  Only 1 NIC is enabled at all times.  Never both and no team/syncing/etc.

Nas:
*Patriot Memory Javelin s4 Media/NAS server, 4 bays, a rebranding of Promise Technology SmartStor NS4600.
*Has Iscsi and Raid 0 Strip (can't find JBOD)
*3 WD40EFRX NASware 3.0

Router: 
Netgear WNDR 4000. 
 
Fixed IP for router. 
 
DHCP for Xfinity broadband 
IP static address for all devices that go through network (print server, Canon Laser Copier/Fax/Scanner/Printer Color all in one office class, the computers/laptops, etc).
IP addresses used for the above in range of of 192.168.1.2 - 192.168.1.30, with 192.168.1.1 reserved for router (note router doesn't assign a name to the NAS even though NAS Computer Name is mediasrv

Router Config Info:  Dynamically from ISP (xfinity)
Category:  Internet IP Address
IP Address (24.130.1.61) 
IP Subnet Mask, Gateway IP Address - all set to Get Dynamically from ISP under the router category for IP Address.  
Shaded out due to using DHCP are:

IP Subnet Mask 255.255.248.0
Gateway Address 24.130.0.1
Wireless Broadcast is off and not used for the NAS

Since I have pulled my hair out making me bald, How do I get this equipment (NAS) to run and allow each drive to be independent (will not be partitioning into additional drive letters, so all 3 Drives will have their own single partition

I spent time reading the last two days on Raid, iScsi and JBOD.  The IScsi and JBOD seem to match my intentions but I had Raid 0 Strip with the 3 drives that weren't NAS designed (WD and 2 Hitachi).

Bought those 3 Red NAS WD for better temp and reliability/performance gained from NAS designed drives

When I run Patriot setup via their windows software or their web gui, it ask for
Computer Name:  mediasrv (which the router is missing for the Ip being used)
IP Address (assuming of the Nas 192.168.1.30)
Subnet Mask (I entered 255.255.255)
Default Gateway (I entered 191.168.1.1)
Primary DNS (I entered 192.168.1.1)
Secondary DNS

I don't get the one beep saying system is ready.  I cannot enable Recycle Bin, or give a Computer Description as it fails to set them up and i have to choose AD Domain or Workgroup and then give a name to the workgroup, but currently not running any AD or workgroup.  I have disabled MacOS, Unix/Linux, FTP, Print services as I won't be using those Os's or features.  Unit will be restricted to LAN only, no outside connection.

I need serious help as there doesn't seem to be anyway to get this NAS up and running without it simply stalling.  It was working before adding 1 Red WD 4tb drive.

Options limited to use what I have, no budget for new NAS box.

I have included an image of the ipconfig report (ipconfig /all) under a command prompt in admin mode.
Link is 
https://1drv.ms/u/s!An88BEuO_UGGcWRCRmAFd2Io0os?e=8rZMAJ

Used greenshot and saved in jpeg.

Comment: *I want to setup each drive as a single physical drive* You must set up each HDD as RAID-0 which consists from one drive, i.e. you'll create 4 separate RAID-0.

Comment: @Akina Correct. And then you share them each individually either as 4 SMB shares or as 4 iSCSI volumes. iSCSI would be more efficient for this setup, even more so if you can use jumbo frames, but that is too much to ask for most home-setups.

Comment: Reply to Akina, okay Raid 0 with 1 drive.by itself.  Pick a folder on each drive to share and I come up with map drive \\192.168.1.30\VolumeX\Test\ (X is the vol in NAS? Test would be share folder or can I share entire drive? Tonny, smb on NAS is 1.0 no upgrd so won't work in win10? Now I raid 0 each drv and then iscsi them or are they 2 different formats. Tried it but iscsi shows no free capacity. They bold iscsi as Block-Level after study this mode allows just 1 computer to access at a time but if only loading iso on 2 devices no threat to content??  Work on above then I will leave response.

Comment: Well still no luck.  It appears that with the removal via windows update of smb 1, there is no way to treat the nas as a nas, leaving me with only iscsi which is to risky for me.  Trying to force SMB1 to work also increases the risk of a hacker getting in my system and ransomware it (they mentioned 2 that were really bad).  I can only find read-only programs for the xfs file system used by the Javelin.  So I am either going to have to keep searching for a solution to smb 1 or possible face having 16tb of movies offline and the server an expensive working brick just not working with win7/10????

Comment: Okay I did some more testing.  I pinged and got a response from the router, my computer and the NAS no errors or dropped packets.  I had a computer that is my Home Theater that is in my bedroom connection to the internet.  I looked to see if it had SMB1 in the Windows Features On/Off and it didn't.  Last time my home theater (HTPC) was used it played movies off the NAS.  However now it can't (but not related to NAS related to the house connection - so disregard this HTPC).  So pings work.  Webgui for Router and NAS work.  The router sees the NAS (by its ip).  Have Enabled netbiosover tcp/ip

Comment: It worked only on the first boot of the day.  However if I reset/reboot either the computer or the NAS hardware, then all connections are lost.  I have all features and services turned on for the NAS and the router has everything essentially changed to default.  Norton Int. Sec and Windows Firewall (the one that stays on even when it assigns Norton the responsibility) have given access for my desktop at 192.168.1.5 and the nas at 192.168.1.30 in both directions and using all and/or tcp/udp.  I am losing my hair too fast, need help why lose connection so easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is typical in almost any use of x86x64 computers it just takes a great deal of fiddling with and then it finally works (Reference Back to the Future when the car wouldn't start, Marty banged his head against the steering wheel and the car started)

I can only present a hypothesis as to the reasons for the problems. As will be bolded below.  I still find problem solving for computer requires your full effort until it is fixed, whether it takes 1 day or 2 months.  As solutions can appear in a googled word or phrase you saw in a message posted on a forum anywhere.

Being able to search previous answers to problems that aren't exactly the same but deal with an issue that you might consider related, out in left field in a Superuser forum post, works!

Things below might have been mentioned in my initial post or responses from others, but listing what I think helped but maybe wasn't the solution to mine but can be a starting point for someone else with a problem like mine.

1)  Reinstall Network Drivers
2)  Keep all antivirus apps offline during process
3)  This might have been the solution, but changing the IP address so the NAS is not 192.168.1.10 but is instead 192.168.1.3
4)  Used a program that supposedly clears any sign of raid left behind.
5)  Using IPCONFIG at Admin level, total release of all settings and then a fresh reset.
6)  Doing a clearing of the settings on the NAS
7)  Changing cables
8)  Direct Connection to the desktop for the NAS (no router)

I honestly think the answer was **#3 and #4 above.  The unit must be sensitive to the IP address it is given and the hard drives even when new and setup via the two methods (the Dashboard Software that came with the Javelin, the other format through windows 7 - 10 (I assume the format process for a new drive is standard or still the same from 7 to 10l  Now I did try a program that actually saw fragments of the previous raid will still on the drive, I tried with UFS Explorer (trial edition), EaseUS Partition Recovery 8.5, EaseUS Data Recovery Wizard, Network Inventory Advisor in my process of riding the drive of any raid fragments.**

Thank you to those who read this and to anyone who replied.